# Почему в telegram aiogram нет ассинхронности?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Сделал телеграм бота, который по АПИ подтягивает видео с YouTube, так как видео большое, требуется время для его загрузки и дальнейшей отправки в боте юзеру.

В момент выкачки видео с ютуба, бот замирает у всех пользователей, как только видео скачается и отправится, бот развисает у всех и всем отвечает.

т.е бот работает как бы в порядке очереди, а не паралельно.

Все функции написаны через await async , у всех так же или у меня что то не так и в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Убедись, что ты используешь асинхронный модуль для выполнения запросов. Например, если ты используешь requests, то это синхронный модуль, который блокирует поток, поэтому твой бот и молчит, в таком случае можно использовать aiohttp или любой другой модуль, который дружит с асинком. Почитай детальнее про разницу между асинхронностью и многопоточностью. Возможно, тебе нужно отправить функцию, которая выполняет запрос в другой поток.